# C++, lint: lint does not discover taking reference to a local variable and passing it on to another function

Tags: c++, variables, reference, local, lint

Why does lint not complain in any of the following three lines in the code sample below?

```
timeout(&a);
timeout(&b);
if (pthread_create(&t1, NULL, timeout, (void*) &a) != 0)
```

Isn't it in always considered unsafe to pass on a pointer to a local variable? And both variables are local...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

static void* timeout(void* c)
{
    int d = *(*((int**)c));
}

static void sendMessage(int* a)
{
    timeout(&a);
    int* b = new int(2);
    timeout(&b);

    pthread_t t1;
    if (pthread_create(&t1, NULL, timeout, (void*) &a) != 0)
    {
        printf("pthread_create() error\n");
    }
}

int main() 
{
    printf("Running..\n");
    int* e = new int(1);
    sendMessage(e);
    delete e;
    return 0;
}
```

Joachim

Comment: Why would it be considered unsafe?

Comment: What makes you think it's unsafe? Passing a pointer to local variable essentially says "I give you access to my local variable." If you do it, you know what you're asking for.

Comment: *Returning* pointers to local variables, that's a different story.

Comment: So long as the variable in question remains somewhere in the stack, there's no harm passing around references to it (downwards funarg problem). So long as that reference isn't maintained (eg. stored in some heap-allocated datastructure) after the stackframe it belongs to has expired, no problems should occur.

Comment: Delnan and sftrabbit: Ok, I forgot to add a deletion of e. Now it is definitely unsafe - what if delete is being run before the timeout call triggered by the thread? If this was a more complex program the memory allocated by e could have been overwritten making c corrupt. Rook: in this example you can see that the reference is not maintained; int* a could very well go out of scope before timeout is called in the new thread.

Answer (score 1):

It is very valid and common to pass the address of a local variable to a function. Sometimes it's incorrect, yes, but making it something that lint would complain about will generate excessive amount of noise/false positives.

Comment: Thanks Chill, ok, I get you, but should it not at least be possible to include this error message by a flag or higher warning level (-w0,1,2,3,4)?

Comment: @user1848056: I've never used lint, but I can't imagine why they have would have an option for that.  It's simply not something that's considered an error.  There are many things that can be done wrong with pointers.  Passing them into functions is no more wrong than creating them in the first place.  In fact, if you create a pointer, it is almost always the case that you are about to pass it into a function.

Comment: Lint is not there to point out errors to you - that is the purpose of the compiler. Lint is only trying to show you harmful code, code that might lead to problems.

Comment: @Joachim: In your previous comment then, were you referring to the compiler?  Because you were the one to use the word error.  If so, then consider my comment about the compiler, instead of lint, it's just as valid.  There's no reason to warn about that, at *any* level, unless you are going to the extreme of warning about any and all usage of pointers whatsoever.

Comment: @Benjamin: With the word error in that context I mean what Lint is considering such a serious problem that it uses the word 'error'. I cannot see that you have made any comment about the compiler, what do you refer to? Can you please explain what you mean with your last sentence, give some examples. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're talking about PC Lint here, but if you are, here's a possible reason: Passing pointers to local variables into functions you call is basically harmless, unless that function keeps the pointer for later use, possibly after the caller has ended and therefore the local variable has no instantiation anymore.

Now, your title misled me by talking about references, whereas the sample only uses pointers and the address-of operator, and pthreads is AFAIK a C library, so I'll only consider pointers.

If in PC Lint you want to indicate that the function called will possibly take the pointer and keep a copy of it for possible later use, you may describe this to PC Lint (9.0) using the 'semantic' option, like

```
//lint -sem(pthread_create,custodial(4))
```

This will tell Lint that `pthread_create` will 'take custody' of the pointer provided as the 4th parameter. In that case, Lint can generate more useful messages. A quick check did not reveal any more warnings. Your issue will be more complex, since you probably need to give `timeout` the custody of your pointer when calling `pthread_create`, to free the memory allocated for `a` when timeout is called, but this complex semantic is currently not supported by PC Lint. I hope this explanation helps anyway.

Comment: At which position in Joachim's example has this lint semantic option to be placed?

Comment: @Strubbl I usually pack such options in a separate option file, but I would suggest to have the option visible to PC Lint before the first 'mention' (probably the prototype) is encountered.